# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null. Error i get in console

Tags: javascript

```
 var button1 = document.getElementById("start");
var button2 = document.getElementById("stop");
var timegraph = document.getElementById("ceas");
var lapButton = document.getElementById("lap");
var lame = document.getElementById("test");
var time = 0;
var ResetStart = 0;
var myInterval;
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var action = document.getElementById("lappara");
function Start() {
    if (ResetStart == 0) {
        ResetStart = 1;
        Running();
        button1.innerHTML = "Pause";
    }
    else {
        ResetStart = 0;
        button1.innerHTML = "Resume";
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
function Reset() {
    time = 0;
    ResetStart = 0;
    button1.innerHTML = "Start";
    timegraph.innerHTML = "00:00:00:00";
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    var aux = action.parentNode;
    aux.removeChild(action);
}
function OnGoing() {
    time++;
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 100 / 60 / 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 100 / 60 % 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(time / 100 % 60);
    var hundreds = Math.floor(time / 10 % 10);
    var thousands = time % 10;
    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    timegraph.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + hundreds + thousands;
}
function Running() {
    if (ResetStart == 1) {
        myInterval = setInterval(OnGoing, 10);
    }
    else {
        timegraph.innerHTML = "00:00:00:00";
    }
}
function Lap() {
    var n = document.createElement("p");
    n.setAttribute("id", "lappara");
    var text = document.createTextNode(timegraph.innerHTML);
    n.appendChild(text);
    body.insertBefore(n, action);
}
```

Whenever i call the Reset() function i get the error above. This code is supposed to be a stopwatch and the Lap() function just creates laps. I looked up some solutions but none seemed to work. Please help me if you can

Comment: There is only one thing accessing `parentNode` in your `reset()` function... that's `var aux = action.parentNode`. Apparently `action` does not have a value. Are you perhaps running the JavaScript before the entire document has loaded? (by putting the <script> tag in <head> for example)

Comment: Can you create a Plunker or JsFiddle? It will be easier to help you on a working/not working example.

Comment: When using `document.getElementById()`, if the value passed in doesn't exist, it will return `null`. So does `lappara` exist in your HTML as an ID? And like @TerrySeidler mentioned, at what point in your HTML is this JS file being loaded?

Comment: My code is running after the entire document has loaded. It is in the body section after the html part.

Comment: Open the developer console, type `action`, check the return value. Also try `document.getElementById('lappara')`and check the value :). Then call `reset` and try again ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can call `Reset()` once but next time you call it the error appears. This is because of `aux.removeChild(action)`. You delete `action` and then you try to get it's parentNode - that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you call func `Reset()` before create element with id lappara by `lap()` func  or call `Reset()`  function several times.

Comment: I know , but yet I don't have privileges to add a comment to the questions... Sorry;-)

Comment: I think you are right. I might have forgotten to call the lap function. Either way I already turned off my computer but I'll check tommorow.